# Working with Stripe and can not figure out the error on these statements

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I'm attempting to charge people different plans depending on their currency using Stripe. I thought another condition in the if statement would be sufficient but whether I pick dollar or euro it seems to ring false and executes the else statement.

```
 //** Now to provide different plans for differnet currencies. **\\ 
 if(isset($_POST['subscription_purchase']) && 'currency' == 'euro')
 {
   echo 'Euro is working';
 }

 elseif(isset($_POST['subscription_purchase']) && 'currency' == 'dollar')
 {
    echo 'Dollars are working'; 
 }

 else 
 {
    echo 'This shouldnt happen';
 }

 The form which this acts on is the following:
 <form action="charge.php" method="post">
    <h3>Sign up to get a new quote every day! Just &euro;400 a month! <small>(Subscription)</small></h3>
    <input type="hidden" name="subscription_purchase" value="subscription_purchase" />
    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email Address" />
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" />

    <select name="currency" id="currency">
        <option value="euro">Euro</option>
        <option value="dollar">USD</option>
        <option value="rand">RND</option>
        <option value="pounds">GBP</option>
    </select>

    <script 
        src="https://button.stripe.com/v1/button.js" class="stripe-button"
        data-key="<?php echo $stripe['publishable_key']; ?>"
        data-amount=40000
        data-description="Wilde monthly subscription"
        data-label="Checkout">
    </script>
 </form>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you are trying to compare two different strings

```
'currency' == 'euro'
```

What you want to do is compare the post that came from your form, like this:

```
$_POST['currency'] == 'euro'
```

and for the `elseif`

```
$_POST['currency'] == 'dollar'
```

which leads to:

```
if(isset($_POST['subscription_purchase']) && $_POST['currency'] == 'euro')
 {
   echo 'Euro is working';
 }

 elseif(isset($_POST['subscription_purchase']) && $_POST['currency'] == 'dollar')
 {
    echo 'Dollars are working'; 
 }

 else 
 {
    echo 'This shouldnt happen';
 }
```

Comment: I had actually tried something similar but now I can see the error I had, thank you so much